# How to generate random LAT & LNG inside an area, given the center and the radius

Tags: geolocation, position, latitude-longitude

In my project my users can choose to be put in a random position inside a given, circular area.
I have the latitude and longitude of the center and the radius: how can I calculate the latitude and longitude of a random point inside the given area?
(I use PHP but examples in any language will fit anyway)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need two randomly generated numbers.

Thinking about this using rectangular ([Cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)) (x,y) coordinates is somewhat unnatural for the problem space.  Given a radius, it's somewhat difficult to think about how to directly compute an (Δx,Δy) delta that falls within the circle defined by the center and radius.

Better to use [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) to analyze the problem - in which the dimensions are (r1, Θ).  Compute one random distance, bounded by the radius.  Compute a random angle, from 0 to 360 degrees.  Then [convert the (r,Θ) to Cartesian (Δx,Δy)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates), where the Cartesian quantities are simply offsets from your circle center, using the simple trigonometry relations.

```
  Δx = r * cos(Θ)
  Δy = r * sin(Θ)
```

Then your new point is simply

```
  xnew = x + Δx
  ynew = y + Δy
```

This works for small r, in which case the geometry of the earth can be approximated by Euclidean (flat plane) geometry.

---

As r becomes larger, the curvature of the earth means that the Euclidean approximation does not match the reality of the situation. In that case you will need to [use the formulas for geodesic distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#From_chord_length), which take into account the 3d curvature of the earth.  This begins to make sense, let's say, above distances of 100 km. Of course it depends on the degree of accuracy you need, but I'm assuming you have quite a bit of wiggle room.

In 3d-geometry, you once again need to compute 2 quantities - the angle and the distance.  The distance is again bound by your r radius, except in this case the distance is measured on the surface of the earth, and is known as a "great circle distance".  Randomly generate a number less than or equal to your r, for the first quantity.

The great-circle geometry relation

```
 d =  R Δσ
```

...states that d, a great-circle distance, is proportional to the radius of the sphere and the central angle subtended by two points on the surface of the sphere.  "central angle" refers to an angle described by three points, with the center of the sphere at the vertex, and the other two points on the surface of the sphere.

In your problem, this d must be a random quantity bound by your original 'r'.  Calculating a d then gives you the central angle, in other words Δσ , since the R for the earth is known (about 6371.01 km).

That gives you the absolute (random) distance along the great circle, away from your original lat/long.  Now you need the direction, quantified by an angle, describing the N/S/E/W direction of travel from your original point.  Again, use a 0-360 degree random number, where zero represents due east, if you like.

---

The change in latitude can be calculated by `d sin(Θ)` , the change in longitude by `d cos(Θ)`.  That gives the great-circle distance in the same dimensions as r (presumably km), but you want lat/long degrees, so you'll need to convert.  To get from latitudinal distance to degrees is easy: [it's about 111.32 km per degree regardless of latitude](http://www.ncgia.ucsb.edu/education/curricula/giscc/units/u014/tables/table01.html). The conversion from longitudinal distance to longitudinal degrees is more complicated, because the longitudinal lines are closer to each other nearer the poles.  So you need to use some more [complex formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Degree_length) to compute the change in longitude corresponding to the selected d (great distance) and angle. Remember you may need to hop over the +/- 180° barrier.  (The designers of the F22 Raptor warplane forgot this, and [their airplanes nearly crashed when attempting to cross the 180th meridian](http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/news/1999043/stealth-fighters-hit-software-crash).)

Because of the error that may accumulate in successive approximations, you will want to check that the new point fits your constraints.  Use the formula

```
Δσ  = arccos( cos(Δlat) - cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*(1 - cos(Δlong) ) .
```

where Δlat is the change in latitude, etc.

This gives you  Δσ ,  the central angle between the new and old lat/long points. Verify that the central angle you've calcuated here is the same as the central angle you randomly selected previously.  In other words verify that the computed d (great-circle-distance) between the calculated points is the same as the great circle distance you randomly selected.  If the computed d varies from your selected d, you can use numerical approximation to improve the accuracy, altering the latitude or longitude slightly until it meets your criterion.

Comment: Thank you for the *excellent* explanation :) I wonder if this (more complex) algorithm http://www.geomidpoint.com/random/calculation.html is about the geodesic distance (that I do not need... we are talking about an area around a given city, so I'm into the 100KM limit). What puzzles me, though, is the point 6, when he talks about the "distribution" of the random number. Is that really a concern?

Comment: it may be a concern. If you select a random number n, within a radius, with a completely random distribution, then locations nearer to the center of the circle will be selected "more often" than locations further away. Think about it this way: Imagine a circle of radius r. Now imagine another circle, centered on the same point, with radius r/2. The area of the first circle is 4x the area of the second. If the random selection could choose a number between 0..r/2 as often as it chooses a number between r/2..r, then one half of the time it selects a point within 1/4 of the area.

Comment: The correction is easy to apply, though.  You just need a random number generator that compensates for that effect.  He even provides it.  `dist = acos(rand1*(cos(maxdist) - 1) + 1) `  I don't know why the +1 and -1 are in there; it seems to me you could drop those.  A modified random number generator like that gives you a distribution of points that is more uniform across the entire area of the circle.

Comment: @Cheeso let's say I want to adjust the randomized starting point to a minimum value, vs. it starting at 0.  I realized this equation `acos(rand1*(cos(maxdist) - 1) + 1)` needs to be modified, but I cannot figure how do adjust it to say `0.25km - maxdist`.

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that the answer is `X + acos(rand1*(cos(maxdist - X) - 1) + 1)`  where X is your "minimum value" @wprater

Comment: That did not work, but thanks for trying, @Cheeso.  I'll ask a couple friends in person.

Comment: That this answer has only 10 upvotes is an atrocity.

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be done by calculating a random bearing (between 0 and 2*pi) and a random distance between 0 and your desired maximum radius.  Then compute the new (random) lat/lon using the random bearing/range from your given lat/lon center point.  See the section 'Destination point given distance and bearing from start point' at this web site: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Note: the formula given expects all angles as radians (including lat/lon).  The resulting lat/lon with be in radians also so you will need to convert to degrees.

Comment: I may have misread the problem.  Do you want a random lat/lon from a point or is it the user picked a random point and you need to determine the lat/lon of that 'clicked' point?